# Conventions when creating or altering an object in a methods

Tags: c#

When designing API methods that either create or alter objects, what would be a clean way so users of the API understand the purpose without thinking twice? Example:

```
class Test
{
    public IList<int> AddItem(int item, IList<int>? result = null)
    {
        if (result == null)
        {
            result = new List<int>();
        }
        result.Add(item);
        return result;
    }
}

var t = new Test();
var list = t.AddItem(1);
list = t.AddItem(2, list);
Console.WriteLine(list.Sum(l => l)); // == 3
```

I am unsure if this follows a convention if there is any. The name "result" for the optional argument is misleading, on the other hand if it was called "existingList" or something similar then another "return" variable inside of the method needs to be used or the then internally misleading "existingList" name could be used. So I am asking for little things but I am also interested in a grand refactor.

Presuming that a healthy object is always being passed for the "result" argument is not an option (because the actually more complicated creation of the "result" argument is supposed to happen in this method).

Comment: This is more a *fashion sense* question, its not really a good fit for SO.

Comment: An `IList<T>` already define an `Add` method, so basically your `AddItem` method is redundant if the list already exists. This makes your code example quite nonsensical - creating an `IList` is one thing, adding items is another. They shouldn't be in the same method anyway.

Comment: If you're interested in clean code in general, I'd recommend reading _Clean Code_ by Robert C Martin. This book is quite popular and nearly all described behavious are generally seen as clean, readable good code.

Comment: The list is really just an example for any object.

Comment: @TvdH creating a [mcve] is almost an art. When done correctly, the chances of getting a good answer Increase dramatically. When done incorrectly, it makes the question much harder to answer.